# Where can i find an msi conditions parser

Tags: parsing, windows-installer

I am looking for a library or utility that can parse the msi launch conditions. Basically i want to take these statements and translate them into our own langauge, but before i do that i need to parse it up.

I can already pull a list conditions out of an MSI, for example:

```
NOT VersionNT OR (VersionNT = 501 AND ServicePackLevel >= 2) OR (VersionNT > 501)
```

But i was hoping there was already something that can break this up into a more interpretable format.

Additional question, what is this language called? I can figure out how to refer to it or search for it.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See:

[Conditional Statement Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368012%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Windows Installer exposes a Win32 function and an Automation Method for evaluating conditions.

[MsiEvaluateCondition Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370104%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[Session.EvaluateCondition Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371656%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I was excited for a minute, but it looks like these functions dont parse so much as evaluate the expressions. Since i am trying to translate the conditional statements into another language, im looking for a something that will decompose the expression into something more easily interpreted, like a tree of operators. The links will be very helpful if i have to build this myself though, thanks.

Comment: The language is proprietary to MSI there are no translators.  Maybe the Evaluate function will be part of a unit test for you though.

Answer (score 1):

Try the Wine source code.  They have the following grammar file for conditions:

http://source.winehq.org/source/dlls/msi/cond.y